# VBA Subscript out of range

Tags: vba

I am quite new with VBA so this might be a stupid question..
I have 2 buttons on my userform, one to search the file and one for the input. (It's just a simplification of what I am doing). Every time I get the error 'Subscript out of range', but I don't know why. Can anyone please help me? Thanks a lot

```
Public file as Variant

Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
file = Application.GetOpenFilename
If file = False Then
    MsgBox "There is no file selected.", vbCritical, "Warning"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdInput_Click()
Cells(2, 2).Value = Workbooks(file).Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: "(It's just a simplification of what I am doing). " - post the actual code...

Comment: But the problem is always in the same place. It's always "Cells(2, 2).Value = Workbooks(file).Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value" that's giving the error. And I just can't figure out why

Comment: You can step through in the debugger...I suspect it's 'file'

Comment: Agree it probably Workbooks(file) - try Workbooks(0) for a start

Comment: "Doesn't work... " - wow! That's a really helpful comment!

Answer (score 0):

From Excel help - "Displays the standard Open dialog box and gets a file name from the user **without actually opening** any files." You need to open the workbook, so something like:

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
file = Application.GetOpenFilename
If file = False Then
    MsgBox "There is no file selected.", vbCritical, "Warning"
    Exit Sub  
End If
Workbooks.Open file
End Sub
```

EDIT: `Application.Workbooks` property doesn't take the full file path, which is returned by `GetOpenFileName`. So in the 2nd sub you don't want the whole file path. Your code should extract just the file's name from the full path:

```
Private Sub cmdInput_Click()
Dim FileName as string

FileName = Mid(file,InStrRev(file,Application.PathSeparator)+1,99)
Cells(2, 2).Value = Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Edited. Please do some debugging on your own if this doesn't work, so you can give some details.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! But I don't really understand what you did there.. Is it right that you just want the name of the file?
So from the string 'file' you want a smaller string 'filename' starting from InStrRev(file,Application.PathSeparator)+1,99. And InStrRev returns the position of Application.PathSeperator starting from the right in 'file'. But why +1,99?

Comment: That's right. From the file's path we extract the 99 characters after the last "\'. I used `Application.PathSeparator`, which tells the system to look for whatever character that operating system uses. It might not be "\" in all countries or instances. 99 is an arbitrary number, chosen as it should be long enough to account for any file name. Ideally, you'd do a little subtraction to determine exactly how many characters are in the file's name.

Comment: use `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` and then the `.GetFileName(path)` method to retrieve the file name